# Qmake failing with SDK 14 / Ventura 13.5.2

Tags: macos, qt, qmake, ventura

So today I installed Ventura 13.5.1 update, and with it SDK 14, and now if I try and run qmake I get the error:

Project ERROR: failed to parse default search paths from compiler output

Is seems that qmake can't find the lib/include paths from the compiler output anymore. Anyone have a solution for this? Short of rolling back the SDK?

Answer (score 9):

OK so the answer to this from the Qt folks is as follows:

This issue will be fixed in the next release of each branch (Qt 6.6, 6.5, 6.2, and 5.15): https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-117225

In the meantime, please manually patch /mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf

- Patch: https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/503172
- Full copy of latest file: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf

Answer (score 1):

The Qt bug tracker also mentions a [workaround](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-117225?focusedId=754625&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-754625) which worked fine for me:

```
qmake ~/foo/bar -early QMAKE_DEFAULT_LIBDIRS=$(xcrun -show-sdk-path)/usr/lib
```